# Keep timestamp when doing search and replace in multiple files with perl

Tags: perl, file

I often use

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' [filelist]
```

to replace each appearance of "search" by "replace" in all files of [filelist]. Unfortunately all files seem to get an updated timestamp. Even if "search" does not appear in the file. Can I change this is a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-i` is loosely:

```
rename($ARGV, "$ARGV$^I") or die $! if length $^I;
open(*ARGV, '<', "$ARGV$^I") or die $!;
open(*STDOUT, '>', $ARGV) or die $!;
```

As you can see, it always replaces the existing file right off the bat. That's where all the prints (`-p`) are sending their output.

Two options:

1. Use temporary files.

   ```
   perl -e'
      $temp_qfn = "temp";
      open(my $fh_out, ">", $temp_qfn) or die $!;
      my $save;
      while (<>) {
         $save = 1 if s/search/replace/g;
         print($fh_out $_);
      } continue {
         if (eof) {  # Not eof()!
            close($fh_out);
            rename($temp_qfn, $ARGV) if $save;
            $save = 0;
            open(my $fh_out, ">", $temp_qfn) or die $!;
         }
      }

      close($fh_out);
      unlink($temp_qfn);
   ' file ...
   ```
2. Load the entire file into memory.

   ```
   perl -0777ne'
      if (s/search/replace/g) {
         open(my $fh_out, ">", $ARGV) or die $!;
         print($fh_out $_);
      }
   ' file ...
   ```

(Both of the above have various resolvable error handling problems. `-i` has some of the same problems.)

Answer (score 2):

Not easily, no.  All that's happening is that perl is overwriting the file with the results of putting it through the regex.

You can do it with a longer program, but there's no simple flag that will stop this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

From [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> `-i[*extension*]`
>
> specifies that files processed by the "`<>`" construct are to be
>        edited in-place. It does this by renaming the input file, opening
>        the output file by the original name, and selecting that output
>        file as the default for `print()` statements. The extension, if
>        supplied, is used to modify the name of the old file to make a
>        backup copy, following these rules:
>
> **If no extension is supplied, no backup is made and the current file
>        is overwritten.**

Emphasis mine.

To deal with this, you'd need to write a program that opens a temporary file for each file in `@ARGV`, reads from the original file, makes a substitution, writes the line to the temporary file, and keeps track of whether any substitutions changed the original lines. When the end of a file is reached, if any `s///` invocations resulted in changes, it would rename the temporary file to the original. [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) will be useful for this as well as the [File::Temp](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) module.